# My return value is 'undefined' but I can console.log() it immediately before the return executes?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I am trying to complete an algorithm question ([link here](https://www.codewars.com/kata/57ea70aa5500adfe8a000110/train/javascript)) and the goal is to 'fold' an array on itself 'n' amount of times I have provided an image to help visualize the goal.

Details:* If the count of numbers is odd, the middle number will stay. Otherwise the fold-point is between the middle-numbers, so all numbers would be added in a way.

The array will always contain numbers and will never be null. The parameter runs will always be a positive integer greater than 0 and says how many runs of folding your method has to do.

If an array with one element is folded, it stays as the same array.*

[visualization of the algo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ymbo.png)

```
function foldArray(array, runs) {

  if (array.length === 1) {
    return array;
  }
  
  runs--;

  let middle = Math.floor(array.length / 2);
  let firstHalf = array.slice(0, middle).reverse();
  let secondHalf = array.slice(middle);
  let isOdd = firstHalf.length !== secondHalf.length;

  let result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < secondHalf.length; i++) {
    let out;
    if (isOdd) {
      if (i === 0) {
        result.push(secondHalf[i]);
        continue;
      }
      out = secondHalf[i] + firstHalf[i - 1];
    } else {
      out = secondHalf[i] + firstHalf[i];
    }

    result.push(out);
  }

  if (runs > 0) {
    foldArray(result.reverse(), runs);
  } else {
    console.log("returning final: ", result.reverse());  
    return result.reverse();
  }
};
```

When executing the following input I get the expected return:

```
foldArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 1)) --> 
console.log("returning final: [ 6, 6, 3 ]") 
return: [ 6, 6, 3 ]
```

But with the following input I get the issue:

```
foldArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2)) -->
console.log("returning final: [ 6, 9 ]")
return: undefined
```

Comment: `if (runs > 0) {` won't return anything, therefore undefined ... the console.log from the second interation - try `return foldArray(result.reverse(), runs);`

Comment: you may also want to think about what array.reverse does, i.e. the returned value will be reversed twice, since you call reverse twice (once for console.log, then again for return)

Comment: Thank you for the note on the .reverse() but I am still confused about the return. In my second example the cosole.log() that is firing is logging the correct answer within the final 'else' block meaning that if (runs > 0) returned false... so I am still confused as to why the return I am getting is still undefined

Comment: did you try `return foldArray(result.reverse(), runs);` so that your recursive code works? Think about what happens when you call that function ... nothing is returned when `runs > 0` therefore, despite calling itself, the original call doesn't return a thing

Comment: @JaromandaX You were totally correct, that was the problem. Thank You!